# Ubuntu reinstall and removing Windows

Tags: system-installation, 20.10

My system consists of Ubuntu and Windows 10 (available as dual boot). I wish to reinstall Ubuntu and remove Windows 10. During the Ubuntu installation process, there is an "Installation Type" section where there are multiple options.
One of those options is:
"Erase disk and install Ubuntu. Warning: This will delete all your programs, documents, photos, music and any other files in all operating systems".

If I go for this option, will it automatically uninstall Windows 10? And will all the storage space be available for Ubuntu as a result?

Comment: In a single word, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choosing the *Erase disk and install Ubuntu* option at the *Installation type* screen of the Ubuntu installer will delete Windows 10 by overwriting it with Ubuntu, and all the storage space will be available for Ubuntu as a result.

[image]