# Factory reset a Lenovo ThinkPad T60 from customised Ubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu, lenovo, thinkpad, windows-xp

my dad passed away and had an old Lenovo ThinkPad T60 which original ran Windows XP.
He had formatted the OS to a customised Linux Ubuntu.
I want to factory reset the machine, but I don't have his passwords.
I tried going into the start-up menu to deactivate passwords, but didn't come right.
I don't know if I am assessing this correctly, but it may be that he removed the Windows XP all together, because that partition comes up with an error when I try and boot from it.
Please help.

Comment: It is off-topic here. But why don't you simply install some OS that you like? Even Windows XP?

Comment: You don't need a password to install a new operating system. It really doesn't matter what is already on it.  If you want to install Ubuntu, follow the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you want to install another operating system, consult support or documentation for that other OS.

Comment: You're light on details; but I really don't see anything on-topic here. Hardware/firmware passwords are unrelated to the OS, same as hardware-resetting is (it's specific to the hardware & firmware on it!).  Yes when you install an OS there is an "*Erase disk and install*" option which as it states, erases the disk & blows away any recovery option that existed on that disk... which is why the installer is asked to confirm the choice! If you remove the OS that controls booting, other OSes on the machine can also be prevented booting & errors are to be expected.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu reinstall and removing Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1302948/ubuntu-reinstall-and-removing-windows)